# set_value object has no attribute in dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was working on some old python code which worked well on Python 3.4.4 and old 2015-16 pandas version I don't remember exactly. But a strange error is thrown I guess some syntax needed to be changed. Hi tried "df.at" and "df.loc" cause similar question have been posted before on the same error but nothing happens for me. Can anybody Help me on this what should I do.

```
class TrimInternalSpaces(BaseRule):
def process(self, df, rule_command, ini_dict, hostname):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for col_name in df.columns:
            if isinstance(row[col_name], str):  # type(row[col_name]) == str:
                if row[col_name].find("  ") >= 0:
                    tmp_val = re.sub(" +", " ", row[col_name])
                    df.set_value(index, col_name, tmp_val)
    return df
```

Comment: Maybe `df[col_name].iloc[index] = tmp_val`

Comment: Should i change line 7 and 8 with this statement.

Comment: Change the line you use `set_value`